# CRM QueryExpression with Link to Same Table / Entity

Tags: dynamics-crm

I am trying to perform the following SQL equivalent query within CRM using a QueryExpression and LinkEntity. Any ideas? I am fairly stumped. I have used the LinkEntity before but not sure how to reference or alias the same entity type.

```
select t1.UoMId, t1.BaseUoM, t1.UoMScheduleId, t1.Name, t1.Quantity
from UoMBase t1
inner join UoMBase t2 on t1.UoMScheduleId = t2.UoMScheduleId
where t2.UoMId = '57E59AB7-AC8F-E511-80F0-005056BE36DF';
```

Which will result in the following entity records:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to convert following to QueryExpression:

```
<fetch mapping="logical" version="1.0">
  <entity name="UoM">
    <attribute name="UoMId" />
    <attribute name="BaseUoM" />
    <attribute name="UoMScheduleId" />
    <attribute name="Name" />
    <attribute name="Quantity" />
    <link-entity name="UoM" from="UoMScheduleId" to="UoMScheduleId" alias="t2" link-type="inner">
    <filter>
      <condition attribute="UoMId" operator="eq" value="57E59AB7-AC8F-E511-80F0-005056BE36DF" />
    </filter>
    </link-entity>
  </entity>
</fetch>

QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression("uom");
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(new[] { "uomid", "baseuom", "uomscheduleid", "name", "quantity", });
query.LinkEntities.Add(new LinkEntity("uom", "uom", "uomscheduleid", "uomscheduleid", JoinOperator.Inner) { EntityAlias = "t2" });
query.Criteria.AddCondition("t2", "uomid", ConditionOperator.Equal, guidID);
EntityCollection result   = OrganizationService.RetrieveMultiple(query);
```

Comment: Added the final code to your answer and it works. I wonder if both my QueryExpression and you fetch could be improved a bit with better aliasing. I wonder if this all just works based on the order of attributes and arguments which isn't ideal but thanks much for the pointer.